# NullPointer with SQLite creation - Android (java)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NullPointerException in my SQLite database.  I am calling the DatabaseHelper class in Results.java by doing this:

```
public class Results extends Activity {
    ...
    DatabaseHelper dh;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    }

    public void showResults() {
        ...
        dh.insert(1, score, percentage);
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; 
    private static final String DB_NAME = "test1"; 
    private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.test/databases/";
    private static final String TABLE = "HighscoresList"; 

    // Table columns names. 
    private static final String RANK = "rank"; 
    private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
    private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDB;

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
        myDB = getWritableDatabase();  //Line 25
    }

    //Insert new record.
    public long insert(int rank, long score, int percentage) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(RANK, rank);
        values.put(SCORE, score);
        values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);

        return myDB.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    }

    //Delete record.
    public boolean delete(long score) {
        //Need this?
        return true;
    }

    public void openDatabase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database.
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath,  null,  SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase(){
        return this.myDB;
    }

    public synchronized void close() {
        if(myDB != null) {
            myDB.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        myDB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("  //Line 62
                + RANK + " INTEGER,"
                + SCORE + " LONG,"
                + PERCENTAGE + " INTEGER"
                + ");");
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

LogCat output

```
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Results}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:62)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.<init>(DatabaseHelper.java:25)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at com.example.test.Results.onCreate(Results.java:33)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
12-18 22:01:53.210: E/AndroidRuntime(6313):     ... 11 more
```

What is causing the NPE?

Also, any help on code structure for this SQLite highscores I am trying to implement would be helpful as well.

Comment: replace myDB with db. db is passed as parameter, and onCreate is called in getWritableDatabase, which is before myDB is initialized affected to the return value (as getWritableDatabase hasen't retuned yet), hence myDB is null

Comment: @njzk2 - Can you specify where you are suggesting to replace myDB with db?

Comment: where the NPE is ... in onCreate, line 62 of DatabaseHelper.

Comment: I changed all mentions of 'myDB' with 'db' and it corrected the problem.  Thank you!